# Telerik reporting, how do get a report to print to the very edge of the paper?

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am trying to design a Telerik report and have text print all the way to the edge of the report. I have set all margins to 0" and in print preview I see everything I want on the paper but when I actually print the document, the right and left edges of the report are cut off. According to the Telerik Document if I see text on the screen I should expect to see that text on paper but that is clearly not happening.

Comment: Can your printer physically print to the edge of the paper?

Answer (score 0):

Each printer has hardware margins which cannot be avoided. You could experiment with another program such as word/excel - the result would be the same.